# Button title gets cropped on click

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dropdown menu for the user to be able to change the displayed data. When the user chooses to select an item, among others a button is being updated.

Let's say in the beginning the buttons title was "Cars", and after selection of another item it is "Example", the button is being displayed like this: "E...le".

**How can I adjust the button size to its title?**

Code for the button:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        ...

        setButtonCars()

        ...

        let tv: UITableViewController = self.children[0] as! HomeTableViewController
        print(self.children[0])
        tv.tableView.reloadData()
        tv.viewWillAppear(true)

        buttonDropdown(self)

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

func setButtonCars() {
        carsButton.setTitle(currentCar.uppercased(), for: .normal)
        let icon = UIImage(named: "chevron")!
        carsButton.setImage(icon, for: .normal)
        carsButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        carsButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 11, left: 3, bottom: 1, right: 0)
        carsButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        carsButton.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        carsButton.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that the button is inside of a UIBarButtonItem.

[image: desc]

Comment: Are you giving width constraint to button?

Comment: @VirenMalhan No. See edit.

Comment: Just, to be clear carsButton is a UIButton and its being added to a UIBarButton item (something like UIBarButtonItem(customView: carsButton)) ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your UI ?

Comment: @Tim - this is on a ToolBar? Is there a reason you're using a `UIButton` instead of a normal `UIBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.sizeToFit()` after changing the title:

```
func changeTitle(_ newTitle: String) -> Void {
    carsButton.setTitle(newTitle, for: .normal)
    carsButton.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Cars button's frame(increase width) such that is can contain the 'Examples' text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But the button doesn't even have constraints in the first place. I forgot to mention that the `UIButton` is inside of an `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of fixed width of the button which might not be enough to hold icon and text. Try increasing the button width.

Set constraint for minimum width of button. You might also like to give maxwidth also in case the text is too large.